# Can I make css sprites match line height?

Tags: html, css

I have some icons I want to appear inline with text, but text has a few different sizes, and I'd like icon size to match text line height.

Currently I'm using CSS background sprites for icons. I tried some shenanigans with `transform: scale` and some others with `background-size`, but it doesn't seem to be doing the right thing.

Is that viable, or do I need to split that into small images which then can be set to proper `height`?

Comment: Kindly provide your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using CSS3, you know the size of your text, and that your images are square (e.g. 50px x 50px), then you could use a combination of `background-size`, CSS variables, and even `transform` if you wish. Take a look at the fiddle below, as well as the code I've inserted here (in case the fiddle doesn't work). The example I've used has a text height of 14px, and the source image is 300x300px, downscaled to 14x14px using variables.

https://jsfiddle.net/u82skrhe/5/

**HTML**

```
<div id='icon' class='one'></div>
<p class='one'>
  this is some of my text here
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
:root{
  --font-size-1: 14px;
}

p.one{
  font-size: var(--font-size-1);
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#icon.one{
  width: var(--font-size-1);
  height: var(--font-size-1);
  background: url("http://placehold.it/300x300");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  float: left;
}
```